# How is setTimeout able to see a private function within a Module?

Tags: javascript, module, scope, closures, settimeout

I've spent a lot of time dealing with understanding this, func.bind(this), func.bind(exports), and function() { that.func(); }. What I can't wrap my mind around though, is how is the following setTimeout capable of seeing and accessing doStuff() in the private scope, when no export for it has been defined in the module?

```
window.TestModule = (function() {
    function init() {
        document.getElementById('testbt').onclick = test;
    }

    function test() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert(this);        //window
            doStuff();          //works! wow!
        }, 250);
    }

    function doStuff() {
        //do stuff
    }

    return {
        init: init
    };
}());

TestModule.init();
```

Answer (score 1):

`doStuff` is in the scope, that's why. It can't find it in `setTimeout(function(){})`, so it looks to the next scope. It can't find it in `function test () {}`, so it looks to the next scope. It finds it in `(function(){})()` and uses that definition.

If you didn't define `doStuff`, it would throw a `ReferenceError` because it will eventually reach the `window` scope without finding it, and there won't be a next scope to look to.

---

Also, I don't think that's your real code; it has a syntax error. Mind posting an actual, working scenario?

Comment: I'd post the real world example, but its HUGE. Do you think anything is wrong with that above design pattern? It is really great, no more this / exports in the onclick event!

Comment: No, nothing seems wrong... except for the syntax error lurking in the corner.

Comment: What if there was a function window.doStuff as well, would it call the window.doStuff instead of the private one?

Comment: No, it would call the private one, because the private `doStuff`'s scope is closer to the current scope than `window.doStuff`.

Comment: what is this concept called?

Comment: What concept exactly? Scoping?

Comment: I don't think javascript looks for the existence of a function in the closest scope and executes it. Is that what you're saying?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. I've read somewhere that it does this, I could look it up if you want.

Comment: I think you're right, actually. I made jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vr57pqwu/5/
If you uncomment each doStuff(), it keeps looking up a level for the function, even in the window context.

Comment: So setTimeout keeps a map of the scopes internally, kind of like a scope chain?

Comment: It has nothing to do with `setTimeout`.

Comment: Do you know of any links that would explain internally how scope walking works in this scenario? Thanks